How to send messages from server to client using async tcp in python?
I am trying to create a GUI chat app that uses async tcp as communication type and PyQT for GUI. I want to be able to send and receive messages both way (server2client, client2sever) but i couldn't figure out how to send messages from server to client. I want to enter a messages as input and click "SEND" button.

        self.connectionButton.pressed.connect(self.connection)
        self.sendButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.send_message_to_event_loop(self.lineEdit.text(), self.type1.currentText()))
        

    
    def connection(self):
        self.conType = self.type1.currentText()
        if self.conType == "TCP Server":
            self.send_message_to_event_loop("Server started", "TCP Server")
        elif self.conType == "TCP Client":
            print("Client")
            self.send_message_to_event_loop("Client started", "TCP Client")



    def send_message_to_event_loop(self, message: str, type_con) -> None:
        """Send the `asyncio` event loop's queue a message by using the coroutine
        `put` and sending it to run on the `asyncio` event loop, putting the message
        on the queue inside the event loop. This must be done because `asyncio.Queue`
        is not threadsafe.
        """   
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            coro=self._async_queue.put((type_con, message)),

            loop=self._asyncio_event_loop,
        )

global_writer = None

async def handle_client(
    reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter
) -> None:

    global global_writer
    global_writer = writer
    while True:
        try:
            data = await reader.read(100)
            if not data:
                break
            message = data.decode().strip()
            print(f"Received '{message}'")

            global_writer.write("hello???".encode())
            await writer.drain()
            global_writer.close()
            await global_writer.wait_closed()


        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            break



TCP does not know about clients or servers. It creates a peer connection where either end can send and/or receive, and either end can kill the connection. Both ends of the connection are equal peers.

Thanks for the answer and information. Do you know how can I send messages then? I still couldn't figure out.

Unfortunately, I am not much of a programmer in Python, I am a network engineer.
